# Pandas if statement in vectorized operation

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "d"], ["", ""], ["", "3"]],
            columns=["a", "b"])
df
    a   b
0   a   d
1       
2       3
```

I'm looking to do a vectorized string concatenation with an if statement like this:

```
df["c"] = df["a"] + "()" + df["b"] if df["a"].item != "" else ""
```

But it doesn't work because .item returns a series. Is it possible to do it like this without an apply or lambda method that goes through each row? In a vectorized operation pandas will try and concatenate multiple cells at a time and make it faster...

**Desired output:**

```
df
    a   b   c
0   a   d   a ()b
1           
2       3
```

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: you can use boolean indexing with `.loc` `df.loc[df['a'] == '', 'c'] = df["a"] + "()" + df["b"] `can you also use `np.where` and `np.select`

Comment: @Datanovice your .loc solution is nice, thanks

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga did you try with a.all() instead of .item

Comment: @davidbilla yes, .all() doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: using `np.where()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "d"], ["", ""], ["", "3"]],
            columns=["a", "b"])

df['c']=np.where(df['a']!='',df['a'] + '()' + df['b'],'')
print(df)
```

output:

```
   a  b     c
0  a  d  a()d
1            
2     3
```

Comment: ended up using this one as df.loc  and mask are slower

Comment: Using lambda should also give the same kind of performance. Not sure though.

Comment: actually not, it was much slower.

Comment: So np.where is better

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you could use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to concatenate both columns, separated by some string using `str.cat`, whenever a condition holds:

```
df['c'] = df.a.mask(df.a.ne(''), df.a.str.cat(df.b, sep='()'))
```

---

```
print(df)

   a  b    c
0  a  d  a()d
1            
2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody already mentioned it, you can also use the `apply` method:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['a']+'()'+r['b'] if r['a']!='' else '', axis=1)
```

If anyone checks performances please comment below :)